# Maven trying to access to unexisting repo

Tags: maven

I am working on a large project with remote private repository.
Someone set one of the reposirories as `http://central`
And on every child's module build maven tries to download from this repo. 
(I dont have any access to it)

Now I am getting this error

```
Could not transfer metadata com.company.project:child-lib-ui:01.111.00.00-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://central): Error transferring file: Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://central/
```

A have already deleted all mentioned "http://central" from all pom's, cleared all local repository, but now Im still getting this repo in build.

What can I do to skip this repo?

Comment: have you seen `~/.m2/settings.xml` ?

Comment: yes. central not mentioned there

Comment: Post your pom.xml and paste some example output.

Comment: Pom is too large to post it, also I have generated effective-pom, and there this repository exist. But I don't understand where it came from.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have this repo declaration in your `settings.xml` file.

Comment: No. this repo isn't declared in my settings file